# code-behind/stylesheet bridge in ASP.NET? add a style to a css selector in code-behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet, bridge

I need to know whether it's possible for ASP.NET server-side code to reference a stylesheet that is in effect on a given page. Is it possible *in ASP.NET code-behind* to get a reference to an existing CSS selector in the stylesheet? Is anything like the following pseudo-code possible in server-side code-behind?

```
     MyPage.Stylesheets(0)("DIV#foo").Attributes("display").Value = "none"


    NOTE:  Assume that <div id = 'foo'>lorem ipse...</div> has been injected
    into the DOM by javascript. There is no server side counterpart to the DIV.
    It was **not** part of the ASP.NET markup:  <div id="foo" runat="server"....
```

Again, server-side, not jQuery/javascript client-side.

I am trying to make a particular DOM element invisible based on some server-side conditions, but that element was instantiated client-side.  I cannot get a reference to it from server-side code, but perhaps I could refer to a selector in a stylesheet?

Thanks

Comment: It's not easy to do unless it has runat="server" to the elements being rendered and add them to the DOM from the server.  To parse CSS directly wouldn't be worth the extra processing it would take, as that could really slow down your application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a way to accomplish this though not using the approach I expected. Visual Studio doesn't like the following but it works:

```
  <style type="text/css" media="all">DIV#foo{<%= FooCSS %>}</style>
```

And in code-behind:

```
         Public Readonly Property FooCSS as String
           Get
             Return "display:none"
           End Get
         End Property
```